# onlyif not working in exec resource

Tags: puppet

```
exec { 'add text to file':
  cwd     => '/usrdata/apps/java',
  command => 'command which writes a line in file',       
  onlyif  => "grep -c -w line-in-file /path/to/file"
}
```

Even though the grep command returns 1, the `exec` resource is getting executed. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: puppet describe exec is your best friend in this situation.

Comment: And you know that the `onlyif` command returned exit status 1 because you ran puppet with `--debug` output enabled?  And you know that the `Exec`'s command is run during the same catalog run for the same reason?  The corresponding section of Puppet's output would then be relevant to the situation.  Otherwise, you are probably going wrong by interpreting whatever effects you do see as the `onlyif` attribute not having the advertised effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: grep -c returns the count, which in my case, returns 1. I know its not working because on every puppet run, the `exec` resourse is being fired.

Comment: You are missing my points: (1) you need to establish what grep's exit status actually is ***when Puppet runs it***.  The exit status when you run it directly and the exit status you *expect* it to return are irrelevant.  (2) it is unclear from your description whether the Exec's command is actually run (vs., for example, the Exec resource being evaluated but its command not run).  (3) The details in Puppet's debug output may clarify the problem for us, everything else notwithstanding.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:(1) I know that puppet is executing the command because timestamp changes on every puppet run. So definitely Exec's command is running. (2) I ran puppet in debug mode, it gives no output on exit status for any command.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Can you suggest the puppet code which can solve my use case? (Describing "use case"  : need exec to write a line to a file if and only if the line does not already exists).

Comment: Supposing that your need is really just to ensure that the file contains the line, not specifically to use an Exec to do so, I'd use [the stdlib module's `File_line` type](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/3.2.1/types#file_line).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `File_Line` deletes everything else in the file.

Comment: @AtmeshMishra, if you observe such behavior from `File_Line` then something is dreadfully wrong on your target machine.  Perhaps that also explains why you report your `Exec` behaving unexpectedly.  I can't even speculate what might cause such misbehavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: What could be wrong? I spawned an entirely new server. It  does same thing. `file_line` is not appending the content instead it is overwriting the file! How do I find whats wrong?

Comment: Since `File_line` is a native (i.e. Ruby) type, I'd start by checking your Ruby.  Ideally, there will be only one version installed on the target machine, so as to avoid any confusion about which is in use.  Make sure it is among the versions supported for your version of Puppet.

Comment: Also, if you're using a master / agent setup then make sure that the master is not older than the agent.  Their versions don't have to be identical, but the major version numbers should be the same, and the agent's minor version number should not be more than one older than the master's.

Comment: Verify also that your version of stdlib is compatible with your versions of master and agent.  Check, too, that plugins are successfully synced, and that you don't have a `File_line` type or provider from some other module present.

Comment: Do also turn on --debug output at the agent (at least), and scrutinize the resulting messages, at least those that pertain to the `File_line` type and the file you're trying to manage with it.

Comment: And make sure you have no other Puppet resource or external process managing the same file, directly or indirectly.  For example, if the whole file is managed via a `File` resource somewhere, then that's the only mechanism by which you should be managing its content.  You should not also use a `File_line`, `Exec`, or other means to separately manage aspects of such a file's state.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your last comment makes sense!! This is what, I think, could be wrong!!
About the "enabling debug mode", what changes do I have to make in `site.pp` to change the logging level? Currently `puppet agent -t` gives me `notice` and `Error`

Comment: One way to enable debug output is to add the `--debug` option to your `puppet agent` command.  That's why I wrote it that way in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec { 'add text to file':
  cwd     => '/usrdata/apps/java',
  command => "grep -q -F -v 'text to check if present or not' /usrdata/apps/java || echo 'text to add' >> location_of_file.txt",
}
```

This will not add text if it is already present in the file.